# Image class and constructor of Bitmap type?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

Well I do not understand how it comes that Image class has a constructor of Bitmap type? I mean, I can do:

```
Image sprite=new Bitmap(...)
```

Why? Its because Bitmap is derived from Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because `Image` is abstract, but `Bitmap`, which extends `Image` is not.  You could just as easily have your code do this instead:

```
Bitmap sprite = new Bitmap();
```

The reason why `Image` is abstract is because it can also represent non-pixel-based images.

Answer (score 1):

> Why? Its because Bitmap is derived from Image?

Well, yeah, [that's what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) (assuming `System.Drawing` namespace):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class Bitmap : Image
```

But it's not the `Image` class that has a `Bitmap()` constructor. Since `Bitmap` inherits from `Image`, all instances of `Bitmap` are also instances of `Image`.