# C# Image/Bitmap Superclass/Subclass Casting anomaly

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I was reading up on C# Image class. This class is abstract. Being as it is an abstract class, I can not make an object out of, but it has a method `Image.FromFile(string path);` that returns a `Bitmap` object. Now in the code, `Image img = Image.FromFile(path)` works, but `Bitmap img = Image.FromFile(path)` does not. However, `Bitmap img = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(path)` does work!

My question is this: Why do I need to explicit cast to Bitmap if the method return type is Bitmap? What is going on?

To clarify: I know that MSDN docs say that the method returns an Image. When I use a breakpoint to check, the Image holds a Bitmap. Even if it did hold an Image, this would be even more confusing for me, as Image is abstract, so I can't possibly have an Image object, no? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Because it return an `Image` not a `Bitmap`

Comment: @Ben Robinson But if I use a breakpoint to check, it is a Bitmap. Image is abstract, and if it returned an Image, would I then not have an Image object, which I can't have because it is abstract?

Comment: Nicely explainded here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571767/image-class-and-constructor-of-bitmap-type

Comment: The method returns an `Image` but in the implementation of the method it must instantiate a `Bitmap` to return.

Comment: @Ben Robinson But that just leads back to the original question... If it is a Bitmap being returned, why do I need the cast?

Comment: Because the method signature has a return type of `Image`, if a method returns an `object` that happens to be a string, you can't treat it as a string unless you cast it. Its the same as if you did `Image myImage = new Bitmap();` you would still have to cast myImage if you wanted to treat it as a Bitmap because it is declared as an `Image`.

Comment: @BenRobinson Can you make this answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of the `Image.FromFile` is *not* a `Bitmap`, it is `Image` [(MSDN Docs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static Image FromFile(
    string filename,
    bool useEmbeddedColorManagement
)
```

So you need the *explicit* cast to get the required type.

---

*Edit. `Bitmap` inherits from `Image` and is defined as `public sealed class Bitmap : Image`. Although when you inspect the object returned from `FromFile` you see the underlying type as bitmap, the method is designed to work on the 'superclass' `Image` so that's what it treats the object as. This enables other types that also inherit from `Image` to also use this method. Classic polymorphism at work...*

Comment: But when I use a breakpoint to check what is in the Image object, it IS a bitmap, and it has to be, because Image is abstract, so I can't have an Image object. Am I missing something here?

Comment: And yes, sorry, explicit not implicit.

Comment: @Comorbid You're almost there. `Bitmap` inherits from `Image` - this is also made clear on MSDN. The function returns `Image`, but as `Image` is abstract the actual type *must* be something which inherits from `Image` - in this case `Bitmap`. Edit: Let's try to be clearer since you grasp that bit already. The return type is `Image` but the actual implementation type is `Bitmap`.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. If you type `Bitmap` in your visual studio, click on it and hit F12, you will be taken to the definition. You will see that the `Bitmap` class is `public sealed class Bitmap : Image` which inherits from `Image`. Your object is indeed a `Bitmap`, but the superclass and the one that `FromImage` returns is the `abstract` class `Image`. This enables `FromImage` to operate on lots of types that inherit from `image` and is a classic case of polymorphism at work.

Comment: @Killercam This is my confusion. Only 2 possibilities, either Bitmap is returned, or an Image is returned. If a bitmap is returned, why the cast? If an Image is returned, then I have created an abstract object, which I cannot do. I know I am being stupid, but to me... Image img = new Image() is not allowed because Image is abstract. Bitmap img = (Bitmap) is pointless cast.

Comment: @Comorbid You haven't "created an abstract object" at all. The function you call has created a `Bitmap` and returned it as an `Image`. You can declare and return variables containing abstract types you just cannot construct an abstract type directly - you construct a derived type. Do some more reading on polymorphism.